# How does one connect to an nginx server from a device other than the computer on which it is running?

Tags: nginx, server, webserver, ip-address, portforwarding

On my device, it is functional and displays:

[Nginx server displayed in local web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukO7R.png)

**Problem**

On other devices, both on the same network and on other networks, when I enter http://192.168.X.X:80 the connection times out on Google and Firefox.

**Some Detail**

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Router: ZyXEL (VMG3625-T20A)
Internet Service Provider: Webafrica (A South African ISP)

**The Nginx Configuration**
I followed a DigitalOcean tutorial ( [DigitalOcean tutorial for installing nginx on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) for installing and setting up nginx on Ubuntu.

- Disabled Ubuntu’s “Uncomplicated Firewall” via: ***sudo ufw disable***

**In the online router configurator at 192.168.1.1:**

1. Momentarily disabled the IPv4 and the IPv6 firewalls.
2. Set router security to low, thereby allowing both LAN access to the WAN and WAN access to the LAN.
3. Set up port forwarding to the IP address reported via the ***ifconfig*** command in the Ubuntu   terminal:

[Port forwarding in the router configurator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIiz4.png)

4. Set up application forwarding with the type of application set to Web Server, which I don’t  really understand, to the IP address mentioned above:

[Application forwarding in the router configurator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2d8u.png)

These adjustments caused no change in the result.